# Methods of showing a map has integral or good reduction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

#### Question

Say we have a map, C->D, of relative curves over a Dedekind scheme, S. What are some of the available methods for showing that this map has good reduction, or integral reduction, at some s∈S? By this I mean: what are some popular conditions that imply this? What are the tricks people usually use?

#### Clarification

By a map having good reduction I mean that both C<sub>s</sub> and D<sub>s</sub> are regular integral curves. By integral reduction I mean that both C<sub>s</sub> and D<sub>s</sub> are integral curves.

You may assume whatever you want, this is part of the question. Assuming, for example, that C->D is generically Galois; or that D is smooth over S; is legitimate. This is pretty open-ended. Hence, community wiki.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might have a look [here](http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/~liu/articles/tokyo.ps).

Comment: Marvelous! This is exactly what I had in mind. Thank you, and welcome to mathoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why there is a map. Why don't you ask when C/S has good reduction? For this, look at Liu, chapter 10.1.

Comment: That's because I was hoping for some theorems exhibiting the interplay between good/integral reduction on the bottom and on the top; taking into consideration other conditions, like ramification behavior.